# Import module from different folder: special case

Tags: python

I've found lots of similar questions, but I think that my case is special one.
I have following arrangement of files:

```
|main.py
|main
    |--__init__.py
```

What I need is to import some class to `main.py` from `__init__.py`.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You have a good explanation of  __init__.py  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this would be helpful for you:

```
from main.__init__ import classname
```

this worked for me